# Am I able to create table using EM Express Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle-12c

Please if someone can let me know if I could create table using Oracle 12c EM Express or also known as dbconsole? In 11g there user will go to schema -> db objects -> tables, but I don't see schema in 12C .[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do that in EM Express.

[Oracle Database 12c: EM Database Express](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/emx-intro-1965965.html)

[I'm trying to perform a task I used to do in DB Control.  Where is it in EM Express?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/emx-intro-1965965.html#A14)

> Although EM Express provides support for basic administrative tasks,
>   it is not a direct replacement for DB Control.  As explained in the
>   Architecture section, EM Express is built inside the database server
>   and cannot perform actions outside the database.  **Also, EM Express is
>   focused primarily on providing performance management and monitoring
>   functionality, and is not meant to be an all-around database
>   administration tool.**

Comment: Nice explanation of EM Express , for +1

Comment: @Badass Papp, thank you so much. I thought so, although  it appears it was able to do in 11g, but I am not sure. I have 12c on my machine and I used sqlplus instead.  Thank you so much again.